# boost asio tcp async_write with respect to sliding window

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp, boost-asio

As far as the `boost::asio` documentation says, the `async_write` function calls a handler after it has "completed". But what does complete mean in this context? As far as I understand the tcp concept, the sender puts data into the stream and the tcp layer takes care of chunking it appropriately to maximize throughput without loosing packets. Correct?
But in this case I don't understand what the `async_write` does. Does it either put the data into a kernel-buffer and the kernel takes care of it then. Where does my program then know if the packets were sent? Or does the function only complete and call the handler if the data has actually been sent? If so, it would be highly inefficient, if not so, it would not be able to already know if there was an error. Furthermore it is not allowed to call more than one `async_write` at a time which emphasizes my theory, that the handler will only be called when data has been put into the kernels internal buffer.
Can anyone clear this up for me?

Comment: yes, sorry, haven't found the thread before. I had a hard time to figure out how to search for the topic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short form: It completes when the OS level call to `write` succeeds for all of the data in the buffer.  This means it has been handed off to the kernel.  The only errors that it detects are errors returned when it attempts to write.  For example, if the other side has closed the connection, you could get an error on the callback from async_write

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wasn't sure about.